# How I can fix this when I create an object with GSON from a JSON?

Tags: android, json, gson

I get the following JSON

```
 {
_id: "5252fdf424f1e7fbf7000004",
address: "Calle 1000",
city: "Concepción",
created_at: "2013-10-07T18:31:19.375Z",
description: "",
name: "Joctos",
phone: "94967994",
updated_at: "2013-12-09T13:03:07.328Z",
happy_hour: {
    active: false,
    type: 1,
    all_day: false,
    start: "2013-12-17T03:30:00.000Z",
    end: "2013-12-17T05:00:00.000Z"
}
```

}

And I think the Store object whose properties are the following

```
public class StoreModel {

@SerializedName("_id")
private String _id;

@SerializedName("address")
private String address;

@SerializedName("city")
private String city;

@SerializedName("created_at")
private String created_at;

@SerializedName("description")
private String description;

@SerializedName("name")
private String name;

@SerializedName("phone")
private String phone;

@SerializedName("updated_at")
private String updated_at;

@SerializedName("happy_hours")
private HappyHour happyHours;
```

//(GET AN SET)

And I have HappyHour object defined as follows

```
public class HappyHour {
@SerializedName("active")
private String active;
@SerializedName("type")
private double type;
@SerializedName("all_day")
private String all_day;

@SerializedName("start")
private String start;
@SerializedName("end")
private String end;
```

//(GET AND SET)
}

But I get the following error when I run the program

at com.example.adicionalesprueba.StoreActivity$1.onItemClick(StoreActivity.java:127)

127: Log.i("Start", _response.get(position).getHappyHours().getStart() );

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your json you have "happy_hour", and you are mapping it in your object as "happy_hours".
Change `@SerializedName("happy_hours")` to `@SerializedName("happy_hour")`.

Comment: Still without work u.u at com.example.adicionalesprueba.StoreActivity$1.onItemClick(StoreActivity.java:127)

Comment: Try to change _id: "5252fdf424f1e7fbf7000004" for "_id": "5252fdf424f1e7fbf7000004", address: "Calle 1000" to "address": "Calle 1000", etc... you can validate your json at http://jsonlint.com/

Comment: intresing detail, but the GSON still worked great when it did not Consider the "happy hour" attribute

Answer (score 0):

there is a typo in your object.

```
@SerializedName("happy_hour")
private HappyHour happyHours;
```

it should be hour instead of hours